# Error Adding Connector To Channel In Microsoft Teams

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I was wondering if anyone had come across the following error (below) when attempting to add any connector to a channel in Teams. I have tried to investigate the error and belie its related to unified groups in 365. Can any help or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few questions to help troubleshoot this problem.

1. Is the user who's trying to create the connector on Office 365/Exchange Online for email? Or is there a possibility he or she has their mailbox on on-premise Exchange? If so that could be the issue but will require further troubleshooting offline.
2. Was the user just recently added to the team from outside Teams (it can take up to an hour for Teams to sync accounts with Active Directory if so). If so, the problem should go away if you try to create it again now.
3. Can you create the connector using Outlook Web Access? (You don't actually have to create one -- just can you get past the point where this error occurs.) If so, then this will require further troubleshooting offline.